# How to Add AngularJS 1.4 in Visual Studio 2015 RC Cordova TypeScript Project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Visual Studio 2015 RC and create a TypeScript Cordova project.

I want to use AngularJS in this project, but after search for a long time, there's no such step by step guide telling me how to apply AngularJS 1.4 in VS2015RC TypeScript Cordova project.

Could someone share me the steps about how to add AngularJS in the TypeScript Cordova project of VS2015RC?

ps. there's a AngularJSToDo demo project, but it's not TypeScript version.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone share me the steps about how to add AngularJS in the TypeScript Cordova project of VS2015RC?

1. Add `angular.js`
2. Get definitions for angular : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts
3. Start using TypeScript `.ts` files like any other angular project e.g. https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/typescript-angular

Comment: I just made a request on UserVoice to add updated VS Cordova-Samples.  Add votes and post comments if you like the idea.  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8207679-create-more-cordova-samples-on-github